# Maven 3 plugin - reading optional depencies of another project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a maven plugin. It's many duty is to verify that all optional dependencies of a specific dependency are provided.

For example current project is named A. One of dependencies defined in pom.xml is B. If we look at pom.xml of B project, we will see it requires C (marked as provided or optional). The plugin should be able to identify this case and throw an error if project A doesn't define C dependency.

The main problem is I'm never able to read optional dependencies of another dependency. Any ideas?

```java
@Slf4j
@Mojo(name = "validate-dependencies", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VALIDATE,
    requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME
)
public class ValidateDependenciesMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    private static final DefaultArtifactHandler POM_HANDLER;

    static {
        POM_HANDLER = new DefaultArtifactHandler();
        POM_HANDLER.setExtension("pom");
    }

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Component(hint = "default")
    private DependencyCollectorBuilder dependencyCollectorBuilder;

    @Parameter(property = "groupIds")
    private List<String> groupIds; // dependencies to be checked

    @SneakyThrows
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        ProjectBuildingRequest request = session.getProjectBuildingRequest();
        request.setProject(project);

        DependencyNode root = dependencyCollectorBuilder.collectDependencyGraph(request, null);

        CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
        root.accept(visitor);

        // option 1. - result is always empty 

        List<DependencyNode> option1Artifacts = visitor.getNodes().stream()
            .filter(node -> groupIds.contains(node.getArtifact().getGroupId()))
            .flatMap(node -> node.getChildren().stream())
            .filter(c -> BooleanUtils.isTrue(c.getOptional()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // option 2. - optional dependencies are present, but version is missing cause it comes from dependencyManagement
        
        List<Artifact> option2Artifacts = visitor.getNodes().stream()
            .filter(node -> groupIds.contains(node.getArtifact().getGroupId()))
            .flatMap(node -> optionalArtifacts(node).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private List<Artifact> optionalArtifacts(DependencyNode node) {
        Artifact artifact = session.getLocalRepository().find(
            toPomArtifact(node.getArtifact())
        );

        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(artifact.getFile())) {
            model = reader.read(fileReader);
        }
        return model.getDependencies().stream()
            .filter(d -> d.isOptional() || "provided".equals(d.getScope()))
            .map(this::toArtifact)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    private Artifact toArtifact(org.apache.maven.model.Dependency dependency) {
        return new DefaultArtifact(dependency.getGroupId(), dependency.getArtifactId(), dependency.getVersion(), dependency.getScope(),
            dependency.getType(), dependency.getClassifier(), new DefaultArtifactHandler()
        );
    }

    private static Artifact toPomArtifact(Artifact artifact) {
        return new DefaultArtifact(artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), artifact.getVersion(),
            artifact.getScope(), artifact.getType(), artifact.getClassifier(), POM_HANDLER);
    }
}
```

---

I think I figured it out. It's all about this piece of code.

```java
dependencyCollectorBuilder.collectDependencyGraph(request, null);
```

Method collectDependencyGraph(ProjectBuildingRequest, ArtifactFilter) is reproducing dependency collecting as it takes place during project build. It's possible to change it by providing DependencyCollectorRequest with a custom instance of DependencySelector.

Comment: It does not make sense to add all optional dependencies automatically. They are optional because they are often not needed, e.g. database connectors for databases you don't use.

Comment: I'm not talking about adding them automatically. I'm talking only about verification.

Comment: Can you give us the bigger picture of the goal you want to achieve with this plugin? So why do you want to download all optional dependencies, which problem will this solve for you? Maybe there is a way to solve that goal with an already existing plugin...

Comment: So the `dependency:resolve` goal is not sufficient?

Comment: What exactly do you want to verify?

Comment: The bigger picture is a bit complex so I intentionally omitted it. Lets say I have a library that uses Spring. I want to add Spring dependencies as provided dependencies cause I want to force developers of applications using the library to maintain and define Spring version by themselves. On the other hand I want to help them by providing info about what they need to add to their poms.

Comment: so the lib supports any or multiple Spring version(s)?

Comment: @cyberbrain exactly... the library is Spring-aware but it's fully compatible with its any modern version

Comment: @T.Dabrowski you are trying to use wrong API, correct one is: [DependencySelector](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/collection/DependencySelector.html), [CollectRequest](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/collection/DependencySelector.html), [RepositorySystem#collectDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystem.html#collectDependencies(org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession,org.eclipse.aether.collection.CollectRequest))